# NSMutableArray Printing Array of Objects with multiple attributes

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I have defined this printDetails method for the Friend and Foe objects which inherit the Character class.

```
-(void) printDetails
{
NSLog (@"\n%@: \nStrength is %ld \nIntelligence is %ld \nSpell is %@\n\n", self.name, self.strength, self.intelligence, self.spell);
}
```

In main I print my array "characters"

```
  NSLog(@"%@", characters);
```

But my output comes out as what looks like a series of memory addresses.

```
(
"<Friend: 0x100204aa0>",
"<Friend: 0x100600320>",
"<Friend: 0x100600170>",
"<Foe: 0x100500330>",
"<Foe: 0x100205b50>",
"<Foe: 0x100102270>"
)
```

Comment: Override `-(NSString *)description` of the class `Friend` and `Foe`, and/or `Character`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are never calling your `printDetails` function in your main.  The result you are seeing are the memory addresses of the *pointers to the characters* in the `NSArray`.

Not the most elegant solution, but to test your function, you can simply loop over the elements and call `printDetails` on each (granted your function is local to the `Character` class.

```
for (Character *character in characters) {
    [character printDetails];
}
```

This should output the result of your function in the console.

Comment: Friend, Foe and Character all have the printDetails method. But the version in Friend and Foe should override the one in Character because they print slightly different attributes. I couldn't get your suggestion to work. I did get it to work with the following code though.                      int num = 1;
    for (Character *theCharacter in characters)
    {
        NSLog (@"%d : ", num++);
        [theCharacter printDetails];
    }

Comment: @Lee The code you just posted is exactly the same, with the exception of printing out an arbitrary counter.  And assigning a type to the element, I've been in swift too long ;)  I will update my answer, but the integer display has nothing to do with the actual solution.  Also, don't try to use that `num` variable as a subscript accessor to your array, Objective-C is 0 indexed, and you would end up getting a runtime-exception on the final element.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with the following code.

```
int num = 1;
for (Character *theCharacter in characters)
{
    NSLog (@"%d : ", num++);
    [theCharacter printDetails];
}
```